# _alloca and std::vector of const char*

Tags: c++, string, memory, memory-management

I did several searches on the _alloca function and it is generally not recommended.
I will have a dynamically updated array of strings on which I will have to iterate often.
I would like to have each string allocated on the stack to reduce the miss caches as much as possible.

Using _alloca I could create a char* on the stack and put it in the vector.
My char will be in a vector which will not impact my stack and I know that the strings will never be big enough to make a stackoverflow when I allocate them on the stack.

Is it a bad thing to use it in this case?

Does the program do what I want it to do?

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>

#ifdef  __GNUC__
# define _alloca(size) __builtin_alloca (size)
#endif /* GCC.  */

std::vector<const char*> vec;

void add(const char* message, int size) {
  char* c = (char*) _alloca (size * sizeof(char*));
  std::memcpy(c, message, sizeof(message));
  vec.push_back(c);
}

int main() {
  const char* c = "OK";
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    add(c, 2);
  }
}
```

Comment: Your `add` function is pretty much broken, the pointer stored in `vec` will be dangling when `add` exits

Comment: Why not just use `std::vector<std::string>`?

Comment: I'm willing to bet a `std::vector<std::string>` will perform pretty well for you.  Have you tried it and measured the performance to know it's not what you need? Also, I think this has UB as `_alloc` should release the memory after `add` returns.

Comment: If it is allocated on the stack and then added in my vector, why would it be destroyed at the end of the function?
If I have no choice I would stay with std::string but when my program runs for a long time I end up with a lot of cache miss that
I would like to reduce

Comment: It ends up destroyed *because* the memory was allocated on the stack. The stack gets "cleared" when a function exits. And how exactly did you determine that `std::string` causes cache misses? Most implementations perform small string optimization

Comment: Your `add` function also has other fundamental issues, such as not allocating enough space for the null-terminator or copying `sizeof(message)` which is `sizeof(char*)` and either 4 or 8 or most architectures (and not whatever the length of the string is)

Comment: @UnholySheep Is it not possible to copy this memory allocated on the stack directly into the vector ?
90% of my strings are too big to be optimized. Thanks for your help.

Comment: When given the choice between slow and correct and fast and broken, go with slow and correct.

Comment: You cannot copy it without extra allocations, since the memory owned by `std::vector` lives "elsewhere". The closest thing you could do would be something like a `std::vector<std::array<char, SOME_MAX_SIZE>>` and manually create null-terminated byte strings there, but that has its own share of drawbacks (e.g.: determining what `SOME_MAX_SIZE` should be)

Comment: I agree, I tried to find a solution, it doesn't work but at least I could learn something.

@UnholyShepp I have thought about this solution but the memory cost would be too high.

Comment: @user4581301 The string I receive is only valid in my function.
I have to process it directly or copy it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stack memory allocated by `_alloca` gets automatically released when the function that calls `_alloca` returns. The fact that a pointer to it gets shoved someplace (specifically some vector) does not prevent this memory from being released (as you mentioned you assumed would happen, in the comments), that's not how C++ works. There is no "garbage collection" in C++.

Therefore, the shown code ends up storing a pointer to released stack memory. Once `add()` returns, this leaves a dangling pointer behind, and any subsequent use of it results in undefined behavior.

In other words: yes, it's "a bad thing to use it in this case", because be the shown code will not work.

There are also several other, major, issues with this specific `_alloca` call, but that's going to be besides the point. This entire approach fails, even if these issues get fixed correctly.

Comment: Ok, there is no choice but to stay with std::string.
Thanks

Comment: @antho there is always a choice. If you know the size of your strings in advance, you can use vector of `std::array`. If you don't, but you can allow dynamic allocation here, you can use your own allocator which doesn't do dynamic memory management.